# Is it possible to color grep output in powershell?

Tags: powershell, colors

I would like to run a java application on windows but color some output lines different background and foreground colors based upon matching text.

Is this possible with Windows powershell? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

- The *Short* answer is simply **no**.
- The *Long* answer is that *anything is possible*, but ...

Unfortunately any coloring and string operations in *PowerShell* is a royal PITA. The reason is that the out-of-the-box Windows console terminals are using their own way to color in/out, and not using escape sequences for coloring.* [See note!] This (AFAIK) always require using `Write-Host`. So any color operations soon become counter productive as they often require extensive Windows *engineering*, to work around too early output and not being able to easily store colors in a string variable.

Either way, here is a more useful solution for highlighting *unsafe* **`ExecutionPolicy`** settings. (Basically a working modification of Antony's answer.) Here it is using a *preset* search criteria (as an array), but could probably be modified and converted to a proper `ColorGrep(<string>)` function.

```
# To get the ExecutionPolicy List
Function Get-MyPolicy {
    $ZZ_EPOL = ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -List) | Format-Table -hideTableHeader @{Label="ExePol"; e={"        {0,-16}: {1,-20}" -f $_.Scope, $_.ExecutionPolicy}})
    $ZZ_EPOL
}

# Colorize the unsafe Execution Policies
Function ColorMatch {
    Process {
        $polkeys = @("Bypass","Unrestricted")
        foreach ($line in $_) {
            foreach ($i in $polkeys) {
                $res =''
                If ($line -match $i) {
                    $iPosition  = $line.IndexOf($i)         # start position of "grep phrase"
                    $iLength    = $i.Length                 # length of grep phrase
                    $iEnd       = $iPosition + $iLength     # end of grep phrase
                    $LineLength = $line.Length              # length of line
                    $iComplete  = $LineLength - $iEnd       # length of characters to complete the line

                    $res  = (Write-Host $line.Substring(0, $iPosition) -NoNewline)
                    $res += (Write-Host $line.Substring($iPosition, $iLength) -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline)
                    $res += (Write-Host $line.Substring($iEnd, $iComplete) -NoNewline)
                    Write-Host $res
                    break  # There's only one match per line
                }
            } # END foreach 2
            If (($res -eq '') -and ($line -ne '')) { 
                Write-Host $line 
            } 
        } # END foreach 1
    } # END process
}
```

To run this, use:
**`Get-MyPolicy | Out-String -stream | ColorMatch`**

The output is:

[image]

Finally, if you need to pass in other strings, you may need to parse the `$line` and `$_` input to separate the strings into lines. Since the script is assuming that there is only one match per line. That is why the **[`Out-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-6)** is used.

**NOTE:**
Recently `Windows 10` has added some [color capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047988/windows-10-console-colors-not-working-virtual-terminal-control-character-sequen). However, there are dozens of 3-rd party console solutions that already does this.

Comment: I want to find AND color-highlight the string "git": `$env:path|select-string git`. How could I use your code?

Comment: Replace `Bypass` or `Unrestricted` with `git`.

Answer (score 1):

As in my simple example below you could try matching your output and colouring accordingly.

```
$Items = @("Find","Matching","Item")
$colItem = "Matching"

foreach ($i in $Items) {

    if ($i -match $colItem){
      write-host  $i -foregroundcolor magenta -BackgroundColor yellow}
     else {write-host $i}
}
```

**--Edit--**

Taking it further with a rough working example (only checked with ps4) "grepping" the Get Help cmdlet output for the Phrase PowerShell. will give coloured ouput for the first Phrase per line

```
 Function Coloured-Output {
    Process { 
       $i = "PowerShell"
       If ($_ -match $i){
          $iPosition = $_.IndexOf($i)       # start position of "grep phrase"
          $iLength = $i.Length              # length of grep phrase
          $iEnd = $iPosition + $iLength     # end of grep phrase
          $LineLength = $_.Length           # length of line
          $iComplete = $LineLength - $iEnd  # length of characters to complete the line
          Write-Host $_.Substring(0,$iPosition) -NoNewline
          Write-Host $_.Substring($iPosition,$iLength) -Foregroundcolor Blue -BackgroundColor cyan -NoNewline
          Write-Host $_.Substring($iEnd,$iComplete)
       }
       else {write-host $_ }
    } # End of Process
} # End of Function
    
$SplitThis = Get-Help

   $SplitThis -split ("`n")  | Out-String -stream | Coloured-Output
```

**########## EDITED With best solution by others ############**

The best solution https://ridicurious.com/2018/03/14/highlight-words-in-powershell-console/ This is a much better and comprehensive answer to the original question than my own worked solution.

```
    Function Trace-Word
{
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias("Highlight")]
    Param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)] [string[]] $content,
            [Parameter(Position=1)] 
            [ValidateNotNull()]
            [String[]] $words = $(throw "Provide word[s] to be highlighted!")
    )
    
Begin
{
    
    $Color = @{       
                0='Yellow'      
                1='Magenta'     
                2='Red'         
                3='Cyan'        
                4='Green'       
                5 ='Blue'        
                6 ='DarkGray'    
                7 ='Gray'        
                8 ='DarkYellow'    
                9 ='DarkMagenta'    
                10='DarkRed'     
                11='DarkCyan'    
                12='DarkGreen'    
                13='DarkBlue'        
    }

    $ColorLookup =@{}

    For($i=0;$i -lt $words.count ;$i++)
    {
        if($i -eq 13)
        {
            $j =0
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $i
        }

        $ColorLookup.Add($words[$i],$Color[$j])
        $j++
    }
    
}
Process
{
$content | ForEach-Object {

    $TotalLength = 0
           
    $_.split() | `
    Where-Object {-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)} | ` #Filter-out whiteSpaces
    ForEach-Object{
                    if($TotalLength -lt ($Host.ui.RawUI.BufferSize.Width-10))
                    {
                        #"TotalLength : $TotalLength"
                        $Token =  $_
                        $displayed= $False
                        
                        Foreach($Word in $Words)
                        {
                            if($Token -like "*$Word*")
                            {
                                $Before, $after = $Token -Split "$Word"
                          
                                    
                                #"[$Before][$Word][$After]{$Token}`n"
                                
                                Write-Host $Before -NoNewline ; 
                                Write-Host $Word -NoNewline -Fore Black -Back $ColorLookup[$Word];
                                Write-Host $after -NoNewline ; 
                                $displayed = $true                                   
                                #Start-Sleep -Seconds 1    
                                #break  
                            }

                        } 
                        If(-not $displayed)
                        {   
                            Write-Host "$Token " -NoNewline                                    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host " " -NoNewline  
                        }
                        $TotalLength = $TotalLength + $Token.Length  + 1
                    }
                    else
                    {                      
                        Write-Host '' #New Line  
                        $TotalLength = 0 

                    }

                        #Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.5
                    
    }
    Write-Host '' #New Line               
}
}
end
{    }
# the last bracket
}


#Trace-Word -content (Get-Content iis.log) -words "IIS", 's', "exe", "10", 'system'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that function only matches the *first* occurrence of "PowerShell".

Comment: @not2qubit  added missing split for each line,  now just first occurrence per line.

Comment: In your edited code, I get: `start index not allowed smaller than zero in line11:           Write-Host $_.Substring($iPosition,$iLength) -BackgroundColor red -NoNewline`
My call:    `$env:path -split ("`n")  | Out-String -stream | Coloured-Output`, `$i=pro` . If $i=Pro, it works..

Comment: It seems that I cannot debug your code because of the magic word process. Is there a possibility to debug?

Comment: The trouble is with case insensitivity in powershell match, equals, like, etc. with  -Match pro and Pro actually match but when I came across the Ridicrious colour match I knew I was not going to match properly it but theirs does. try their coulou match using Trace-Word -content ($env:path -split ("n")) -words "pro"